# paginate related queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have  two models named Card and Comment, both are related with a foreign key

```
class Card(models.Model):
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=30, null = False, blank=False, default="")
    mobile = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=12, null = False, blank=False, default="")
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, null = False, blank=False, default="")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Comment(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    valid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to access card along with limited (comment size say 5) comments with select_related or prefetch_related query

I have a load more button for comments, so when ever i press load more i want 5 more comments to be fetched

someone pls answer, thnks:)

Answer (score 0):

**To paginate a queryset in Django, you can use the Paginator class:**

This will paginate the queryset, allowing you to access only the items on the specified page.

To paginate a queryset that includes related objects, you can use the select_related method to prefetch the related objects.

Here's an example:

```
# Assume that your queryset includes related objects, and that you want to prefetch them
my_queryset = Comment.objects.filter(image__id=your_id).values("comment")

# Create the paginator object as described above
paginator = Paginator(my_queryset, 5)

# Get the page number from the query string
page_number = request.GET.get('page')

# Get the page object for the specified page number
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

# Use the page object to access the items on the specified page
page_items = page_obj.object_list
```

Comment: I only want one object based on id and related objects with limited results

Comment: so using card id you want to get paginated comments right?

Comment: yes also the card along with it

Comment: you can separately call Card model to get particular card - its all depends how you want the output data.

Comment: I am figuring out if it can be done in one query or one db hit

Comment: yeah it can be done - but card fields will be present each object - you can do Comment.objects.filter(image__id=your_id).values("comment", "image__image", "image__email", "image__mobile", "image__name")

Comment: but i will say its not good idea to include single card detail in each comment object : can you specify how you wan the output queryset

Comment: will that be any performance issue??

Comment: what i need is card with comments show below, but only limited comments, so that each time i hit load more 3 more comments should be fetched from backend, like wise etc
all i want is the optimized code for this problem (optimized in terms of memory, db hits and number of queries)

Comment: will that be a performance issue?

Comment: Its not good solution to combine card and comments in single queryset ;
Instead : Hit the card model only once then you can hit the comment model again and again as requred;

so create load_more(request) function where you can put above solution code : and call this load_more function on each call of load_more button - using ajax